# Laravel 5 API Routes Returning a 500 Error to Frontend

Tags: angularjs, api, routes, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to start a new project in Laravel 5, and I'm running into some routing issues. I used Laravel 4 before for something similar, but I'm new to laravel 5.

What I'm trying to do is create a demo application with an AngularJS frontend, and Laravel as a backend server and API for data. I have gulp build my frontend into laravel/public/app, so my structure looks like this:

```
laravel
 - app/
 - frontend-src/
 - public/
 -- app/
 --- index.php
 --- js/
 --- css/
 --- views/
```

I configured Laravel to look for views starting in public/app like this in laravel/config/view.php:

```
'paths' => array(__DIR__.'/../public/app'),
```

Then I configured my routes to load the Angular index page for '/' and a Route Group for my API calls like this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function() {

    Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectController');

});
```

I'm serving it in development by using the artisan server and running it with `php artisan serve` - and this works fine. The index page loads, my Angular application is visible, and the homepage looks correct.

However, when I added a service call to GET /api/projects in the home page, the server responds with a 500 error

```
GET http://localhost:8000/api/projects 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

At first I thought I named something wrong or the routes were not setup, so I ran the command php atisan route:list - but the routes look fine:

```
+--------+----------+------------------------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                          | Name                 | Action                                         | Middleware |
+--------+----------+------------------------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                            |                      | Closure                                        |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/projects                 | api.projects.index   | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectController@index   |            |
|        | POST     | api/projects                 | api.projects.store   | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectController@store   |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/projects/create          | api.projects.create  | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectController@create  |            |
|        | DELETE   | api/projects/{projects}      | api.projects.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectController@destroy |            |
|        | PATCH    | api/projects/{projects}      |                      | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectController@update  |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/projects/{projects}      | api.projects.show    | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectController@show    |            |
|        | PUT      | api/projects/{projects}      | api.projects.update  | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectController@update  |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/projects/{projects}/edit | api.projects.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectController@edit    |            |
+--------+----------+------------------------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

In the ProjectController, the index method is only one line:

```
return Response::json(array('success' => true));
```

Does anyone see what I'm missing, or what my /api routes would not not working?
Thanks for your time, all!

Comment: Is ProjectController namespaced correctly? (Sorry for posting something obvious...but, I ask based on person experience.)

Comment: I think so, but then again I'm used to Laravel 4.
The namespace in the controller file is "namespace App\Http\Controllers;",and it's declared as "class ProjectController extends Controller".

Comment: Cool, I ended up being able to get more information to help debug it.
Thanks for helping me look into this, @Roger!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the solution was something dumb simple, and it had two parts.
First, a controller method (ProjectController@index, in this case) MUST return something. Second, I found an error when I checked the Network tab in the developer console -- the 500 error was returning more information in the full response.

Apparently, to use "Response::json(...)" in Laravel 5, you must either include it via

```
use Response;
```

or namespace the class and write `\Response::json(...)` .

I included it via a use statement, and the API call returned as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You must set the request whether its Get or Post like following...

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function() {
    Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectController');
    Route::get('projects','ProjectController@projects');
});
```

Now the routes allows you to return the json code from function project.
PS: if this not working let me know.